# Consumer goods question

Tags: meaning

What is a better definition, the consumer business industry or the consumer goods industry?? And also, is there an acronym??

I am in between those two, would really appreciate your help

Comment: Can you give an example for a product that falls into your current subject?

Comment: The usual acronym is "B2C" or "business to consumer" as opposed to "B2B" or "business to business".

Answer (score 2):

Consumer Business Industry generally would consist of a few related sectors such as consumer product companies, retail, wholesale and distribution, and travel, hospitality and leisure.
Consumer goods industry in business parlance refers to tangible commodities used by the consumer.

Answer (score 1):

**Fast-Moving Consumer Goods** (FMCG) or **Consumer Packaged Goods** (CPG)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast-moving_consumer_goods